# When exiting html5 full screen mode css media queries don't work - safari

Tags: css, html, safari, fullscreen

I'm using HTML5 full screen mode on browsers that support it (can't share link to code yet, it's not live). I've run into a problem that I think maybe an Safari bug, but I wanted to also post here to see if anyone had suggestions on a workaround.

My app is using an image slider that has a div with links above it for hover effects (tough to explain, but bear with me). The default width of both the images and the hover DIV are 1150 pixels (via CSS), and using a media query to specific the links div width (this is SCSS code, so it may look funny to those not used to it).

```
.links {
    width: 1150px;
    height: 744px;      
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
     @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        width: 910px;
        height: 588.77px;
    }    
}
```

I also provide a way to go to full screen (via HTML5 full screen) and that specifies a custom width / height for this div (because screen sizes will vary, and my links have to hover at certain positions, using percentages). All of this is working fine. Drag the browser around between under and over 1200px wide and the hover states scales properly with the image. Go to full screen, everything scales appropriately on the image and the hovers. However if I start in a browser that is 
1) sized below 1200 pixels 
2) go to full screen
3) then exit full screen mode **in safari only** it doesn't scale based on the media query and leaves the .links class sized at 1150 pixels wide.

If I resize anything, it goes back to working / scaling properly.

I can't think of a way to trigger the CSS media query outside of a resize event. I don't want to add a separate class via jQuery on my exit of fullscreen because I'd have to remove it on subsequent resizing.

Any other suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did a mockup outside of my app with the same conditions (with none of the other code) and realized this was working in Safari in that test. I was using:

```
$(document).stop(true, true);
```

in an event bound to exiting full screen. Apparently Safari didn't like this. Now that that is removed, it works fine in Safari again.